# Matryoshka Words!

Tags: word

A Matryoshka doll is a set of wooden dolls of decreasing size placed one inside another. We're gonna do the same thing with words. Let's call it Matryoshka Words. A solution to this puzzle *should contain every word in the chain*. Each word in the chain adds a letter to the previous word's letters. The order of the letters does *not* matter.

For example, if I said *top cards inside emptiness* that would be: *aces -> space*.

Here is the definition of these Matryoshka Words:

**A musical note** *inside* **a rodent** *inside* **a cover** *inside* **on the left side** *inside* **a door** *inside* **a meddler** *inside* **a bone** *inside* **officers** *inside* **a springboard**.

Comment: *Aces* is not "inside" *space* unless you're allowed to rearrange the letters. Is that what you mean by "X inside Y", that Y contains all the letters of X?

Comment: But "space" doesn't contain "aces".  Should that be "paces"? Or is reordering allowed?  @Silenus lol get out of my head

Comment: @Rubio ninja'd by 6 seconds :P

Comment: The letters making up 'aces' is inside 'space'. Yes the it's about the letters in the words, not the order of the letters.

Comment: I included the example to clarify that point. Should I be more explicit?

Comment: Yes; the example and the text on a casual reading suggest opposite things, and the usual convention with such puzzles is that the stem word remain unchanged throughout. (Also, it would be strange if opening a doll layer caused it to become commingled with its contents!)

Comment: @Rubio, but I like it in here. Anyway, I think this is quite an interesting puzzle-type, except that the Matryoshka name would be better suited to series like {a, cat, scats} where each word is *properly* embedded in the next. But how many such series are there like *that* in English?!

Comment: Yeah I guess I am defying physics here! :)

Comment: `a bone inside officers inside a springboard`. Is the solution for officers the same for bone -> officers and officers -> springboard?

Comment: Does each move in the chain add a *single* letter? That's what's suggested by your current wording.

Comment: Yes each move adds a single letter. And each element of the definition represents a single word.

Comment: Could have called it an 'addagram'.

Comment: @NeilW I should have run this by you first! I think I'll go with that next time! :)

Comment: @NeilW I like that! :)

Comment: It doesn't have that iterative sense you want here though, but I like it for the step.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sequence seems to be:

> ta  — a note (a "ta" is a quarter note)
>  rat — a rodent
>  tarp  — a cover
>  aport  — on the left side
>  portal  — a door
>  marplot  — a meddler
>  temporal  — a bone
>  patrolmen  — officers
>  trampoline  — a springboard

Comment: You got it! :) Nice work as usual!!

Comment: If I use this again, I'll go with 'Addagram' as Neil W aptly suggested! :)

Comment: Is there a restriction against one-letter words? Couldn't "a" be the first word here? Or is "a" only a word if it's in a sentence?

Comment: Next time I'll start with a one-letter word. Great idea! :)

Comment: I started with the assumption that the musical note would be A and was considering word lengths one too short for a bit (leading to the very promising "top" as a cover and "port" for on the left, until I noticed those would never reduce to any note in A to G), then realizing the first assumption was wrong. Great misdirection - I think it worked in the puzzle's favor to NOT start with a single letter word here :)

Comment: here you go, a nice answer badge. +1!