# Russian Nesting Words

Tags: wordplay, language, word-sequence

Consider the words *a*, *rat*, and *aerate*. These words form a series, each nested in the next:

> a, rat, aerate.

Such a series can be encoded with a clue consisting of the following:

- **synonyms** of the words in the series
- **nothing else**.

For example, the above series can be encoded with the clue:

> Introduce air into an animal.

Parsing this clue, we get:

```
Introduce air into | an | animal
AERATE               A    RAT
```

---

Now that you know the rules, let's see if you can find the series clued by the following:

1. Consumer swallowed audience member
2. Refurbished egg-shaped vessel
3. Vermin gadfly of Athens put in a box
4. Low-quality beige table
5. Spirit destructively getting older

<sub>*This puzzle was inspired by [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/matryoshka-words) of [wildBillMunson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/6094/wildbillmunson).</sub>

Comment: Regarding the green tick, I will award it to the first person to post three solutions that have not been posted previously. If nobody gets three on their own, I will award the tick to the first person to post two solutions that have not been posted previously. If nobody gets two on their own, I will award the tick to the first person to post a solution.

Comment: Great puzzle! +1

Comment: Do nested words need to be completely contained, such as ae(r(a)t)e, or can they touch the edges of the word - ((a)nd)roid?

Comment: @Zxyrra, they cannot touch the edges, much the same way a smaller Matryoshka doll cannot share a surface with the larger Matroyoshka doll it's contained in.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's 5 of 5:

Consumer swallowed audience member

> eater | ate | theatergoer

Refurbished egg-shaped vessel

> renovated | ovate | vat

Vermin gadfly of Athens put in a box

> rat | Socrates | crate

Low-quality beige table

> substandard | tan | stand

Spirit destructively getting older

> gin | damagingly(?) | aging

Comment: @Zachstein beat you to #2! Nice job with the others.

Comment: I got ninja'd again!

Comment: @MikeQ but you will get the accepted answer for getting 3 or 2 first

Answer (score 7):

2) Refurbished | egg-shaped | vessel

> renovated | ovate         | vat

3) Vermin gadfly of Athens put in a box

> rat | Socrates   | crate

Five could maybe also be 
5) Spirit | destructively | getting older

> soul | murderously | moulders

Comment: Make sure you have tenses correct for each word.

Comment: I think you have to preserve the order of the letters.

Comment: @MikeQ I was thinking that but wasn't sure. I think it popped into my head after looking at the puzzle it was inspired from.

Comment: The order of the letters must be preserved. See my comments on that original puzzle. But nice find in any case!

Answer (score 6):

Number 5 could be
Spirit – destructively –  getting older

> gin – ravagingly – aging

Comment: Make sure you have the part of speech correct for each word. Also, 5 is, I just noticed, underdetermined.

Comment: Better like this? At least, now it's an adverb.

Comment: What does it tell about me that I got the spirits question right?