# More Russian Nesting Words

Tags: word, wordplay, language

Consider the words *he*, *mother*, and *smothered*. These words form a series, each nested in the next:

> he, mother, smothered.

Such a series can be encoded with a clue consisting of the following:

- **synonyms** of the words in the series
- **nothing else**.

For example, the above series can be encoded with the clue:

> That man suffocated mom

Parsing this clue, we get:

```
That man | suffocated | mom
HE         SMOTHERED    MOTHER
```

---

Now that you know the rules, let's see if you can find the series clued by the following:

1. Favorable signs flavor photograph
2. Purplish-red plant generation
3. Captives label all the world, according to Shakespeare
4. Tear banded stomach tissue
5. Nether perennials have an obligation

<sub>*This puzzle was inspired by [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/matryoshka-words) of [wildBillMunson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/6094/wildbillmunson).</sub>

Comment: Regarding the green tick, I will award it to the first person to post three solutions that have not been posted previously. If nobody gets three on their own, I will award the tick to the first person to post two solutions that have not been posted previously. If nobody gets two on their own, I will award the tick to the first person to post a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Favorable signs flavor photograph

   > AUSPICES, SPICE, PIC
2. Purplish-red plant generation

   > MAGENTA, AGENT (thanks @ChrisCudmore), AGE
3. Captives label all the world, according to Shakespeare

   > HOSTAGES, TAG, STAGE
4. Tear banded stomach tissue

   > RIP, STRIPED, TRIPE
5. Nether perennials have an obligation

   > LOWER, FLOWERS, OWE

---

**Feedback section**

Subjective order of difficulty (easiest to hardest): 3, 5, 4, 1, 2. Although I got 5 first, I'd say 3 is easier because "all the world, according to Shakespeare" only has one possible meaning.

In general, what makes the clues harder is **multiple possible meanings of a word**. For instance, "tear" could mean as in crying; once I realised it meant as in "rip", 4 was easy. 2 was the hardest because even once I got the innermost and outermost words, I couldn't find the right middle word because I was too hung up on the more obvious meaning of "plant". Also, of course, more obscure words tend to make clues harder. I'd never have thought of "auspices" without help from a thesaurus.

Comment: The word youre looking for is AGENT.

Comment: @Chris Oh, THAT kind of plant!!! See what I mean about multiple possible meanings of a word?

Comment: Yes, it's all state of mind.

Comment: Your difficulty ratings seem correct to me. I didn't think this one was hard. Just a quick little puzzle for anyone willing to do it.

Comment: @Silenus It was fun! :-)